# How can I completely delete a song from Frets on Fire?

Tags: frets-on-fire

I have a song I want to delete.  I went to `"C:/Program Files/Frets on Fire/data/songs/song-to-delete"` and deleted the folder song-to-delete.  When I open the game, it's still there.  It won't play, just chokes on an error because I deleted the files for it.  How can I get rid of the cassette?  Is there any way to *completely* delete a song from Frets on Fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the solution [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080422231428AAbpoUc).

Quoting from the site:

> go to frets on fire folder on my
>   computor or whereever u can find it.
>   click on data. click on songs then
>   click on the song or the folder u want
>   2 delete and it should delete the song
>   and cassette so it doesnt show up

**Edit:** Did you check the folder under %appdata%? It seems the program is still looking at another place. The simplest solution is just search your hard drive for that song name. You will probably get a folder somewhere in your application data folder also. Try deleting it from there and restarting the program.

Comment: I already found that site and tried that (as mentioned in my question).  It didn't work for me.

Comment: @John I have updated my answer.

Comment: That did it.  It was hiding in appdata.  Thanks a lot.